# Client socket.startHandshake() failed when adding SSL support for an EPPServer which is based on netty.

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, netty

I am working on a program to support SSL for an EPP server, and here are the code which based on the netty offical example:

```
public void start(final int port, final String type) {
    try {
        ServerBootstrap boot = new ServerBootstrap();
        boot.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        if (type.equals("EPP/SSL")) {
                            SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslEngine);
                            ch.pipeline().addFirst(sslHandler);
                        }
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new EppDecoder(),new EppHandler(service));
                    }

                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        this.port = port;
        boot.bind(this.port).sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is how I get the keystore and init the channel:

```
String algorithm = Security.getProperty("ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm");
    if (null == algorithm) {
        algorithm = "SunX509";
    }
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        String file = FileLocator.getPath(this.keystorePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ks.load(fileInputStream, this.keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        kmf.init(ks, this.keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        SSLContext serverContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        this.sslEngine = serverContext.createSSLEngine();
        this.sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Failed to initialize the server-side SSLContext", e);
    }
```

after this, I use the verisign epp tool to debug it. Unfortunately, with the source code of epp tool, I find it failed:

```
    public static Socket createSocket ( String aHost, int aPort, int aTimeout,
        SSLSocketFactory aSslSocketFactory ) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException, Exception {
    if ( aHost == null || aHost.trim().length() == 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "SecureSocket.createSocket(): host name is invalid" );
    }
    if ( aPort < 0 || aPort > 65535 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invlaid argument: aPort" );
    }
    if ( aTimeout < 0 ) {
        aTimeout = 0;
    }
    SSLSocket socket =
            (SSLSocket) aSslSocketFactory.createSocket( aHost, aPort );
    if ( aTimeout > 0 ) {
        socket.setSoTimeout( aTimeout );
    }
    socket.startHandshake();//failed here
    return socket;
}
```

I create the Certification file with keytool and import it into the epp client keystore, but it seems don't work. When the type is not "EPP/SSL", the origin code still works. Why the SSL socket hand shake failed?

Comment: Failed how? Where have you told us what actually haooened?

Comment: When debug here, after 30 seconds it throws exception: protected void createSocket () throws EPPException {
  try {
   setSocket( SecureSocket.createSocket( getHost(), getPort(), getTimeout(),
     this.sslSocketFactory ) );
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) {
   throw new EPPException( "Cannot create socket connection", e );
  }
 }

Comment: That's not what happened. That's *the code that reported what happened.* ***What was the exception?*** I shouldn't have to ask this question twice. I shouldn't have to ask it once. You should have posted the stack trace in your question in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a new `SSLEngine` for each connection. It looks like your code creates one a single `SSLEngine` instance and then use it for all SSL connections. It will never work.

The recommend way of initializing an SSL connection is to use `SslContext` in `io.netty.handler.ssl`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SslContext sslCtx = SslContext.newServerContext(...);
    ServerBootstrap b = ...;

    b.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            if (type.equals("EPP/SSL")) {
                SslHandler sslHandler = sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc());
                ch.pipeline().addFirst(sslHandler);
            }
            ...
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is no evidence of that whatsoever.

Comment: Looking from the first and the second snippet? It is not easy to tell though, because the question has missing information.